# Powershell text File to CSV file conversion line by line

Tags: powershell

Task: Convert screen scraped text into csv for import into Excel.
Environment: Windows 11, Notepad, Powershell ISE, Powershell v5.1
Text format: Single line per entry with CR LF endings, checked with Scite.
Text to convert has repeating 7 line pattern ending in line containing a unique
word followed by empty (CR LF) lines. Number of empty lines is inconsistent.

My Solution:
Read each line.
If line contains unique word, append line to file maintaining CR LF.
If line is blank do nothing.
If line does not contain unique word, convert CR LF to comma and append to out file.
Input file sample:

```
28
--
123.123.123.123 - fgh1
00:00:00:00:00:00
someword
 anotherword
INDEX word: 11


29
--
123.123.123.124 - fgh1
00:00:00:00:00:00
someword "INDEX
 anotherword
INDEX word: 11
```

Output file format desired:

```
28,--,123.123.123.123 - fgh1,00:00:00:00:00:00,someword, anotherword,INDEX word: 11
29,--,123.123.123.124 - fgh1,00:00:00:00:00:00,someword, anotherword,INDEX word: 11
```

This PS script recognizes the unique word(s):

```
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(C:\InFile.txt))
{
 If ($line -match "INDEX" {Write-Host "Line contains INDEX"}
 ElseIf ($line -notmatch "INDEX") (Write-Host "Line does not contain INDEX"}
 }
```

However, I cannot get the following script to replace the CR LF with commas and produce the file format I desire.
The script just writes out the original file format to the OutFile.

```
foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(C:\InFile.txt))
{
 If ($line -match "INDEX" {Out-File -append -FilePath C:\OutFile.txt -inputobject $line}
 ElseIf ($line -notmatch "INDEX") (Out-File -append -filepath C:\OutFile.txt -inputobject ($line -replace '\r?\n',',')}
 }
```

Note on why I'm using the [System.IO.File]::ReadLines method: I couldn't get proper unique word matches using:

```
$FilePath = "C:Infile.txt"
$FileContents = Get-Content -Path $FilePath -Raw | Out-String #Tried with or without "Out-String"
ForEach ($Line in $FileContents){
If ($Line -match -match "INDEX" {Write-Host "Line contains INDEX"}
ElseIf ($line -notmatch "INDEX") (Write-Host "Line does not contain INDEX"}
 }
```

Comment: If you simply omit the `-Raw` switch you will get an array of lines from `Get-Content`.

Comment: Thank you, my research led me to believe that adding -Raw actually returned strings not objects. The Get-Content code now detects the "INDEX" line. I still have the replace CR LF with comma part to get working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the data from such a file like below:

```
$fileIn  = 'C:\inFile.txt'
$fileOut = 'C:\OutFile.txt'
$headers = (1..7 | ForEach-Object { "Column$_" } ) -join ','     # create a header line for the csv file

# read the file as single multiline string and parse the data
$data = (Get-Content -Path $fileIn -Raw) -split '(\r?\n){2,}' |  # split the text on the multiple Newlines
Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } |                                # ignore empty or whitespace-only parts
ForEach-Object { ($_ -split '\r?\n') -join ',' }                 # split each part on Newline and join the elements with a comma

# write the headers to csv file, then the data
$headers | Set-Content -Path $fileOut
$data | Add-Content -Path $fileOut
```

P.S. Your example does not make it clear to me why you should look for the word `INDEX` as both data blocks have that..

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the comments. This solution works. I was unclear about needing a header line. The INDEX line is the last line in each record.  I process some records that have no regular length with the only commonality being the last line in each record. I previously converted these using BAT, VBS or even C, using the last line of each record to split them. I was hoping PS would be simpler. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

this may help, but finally u need to define a header line:

```
$content = (gc C:\inFile.txt | ?{$_}) 
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::New()
$newContent = @(
    foreach ($line in $content){
        $list.add($line)
        If ($line -match '^index'){
            $list -join ','
            $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::New()
        }
    }
)
$newContent | set-content .\myCsv.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately, for me, this is too terse.